Why does .verticalScroll(state = scrollState) on my android compose modifier always scroll the screen to the bottom of the view
In my current android project i am employing the following modifier values to enable my displayed dialogs to show all screen contents when there is a large amount of data to show or the physical device screen size is not large enough to display the dialogs content
Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            FormEditText(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .focusRequester(moduleNameFocus)

however when the dialog displays on a smaller screen it is scrolling to the bottom of the dialog contents.
i have tried both the following solutions however nothing has had the desired effect
 val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

and
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
   moduleNameFocus.requestFocus()
    scrollState.scrollTo(0)
}

why does the dialog contents scroll to the bottom of the dialog contents
and how can i get it to keep at the top of the dialog and not scroll down on first display of the dialog?

It is likely due to the initial scroll position being set to the bottom by default. You can use the scrollTo method with a value of 0 after the dialog has been laid out.
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
        .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    FormEditText(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(moduleNameFocus)
    )
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    moduleNameFocus.requestFocus()
    scrollState.scrollTo(0)
}


I have already tried that and it has no effect
